# Why does this subsequence (successive terms less than 2^{-k}) exist?

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading this proof of the completeness of $L_p$ by Bartle, I don't understand how did he claim without proof that there exists a subsequence $(g_k)$ of $(f_n)$ such that $\|g_{k+1}-g_k\|_p<2^{-k}$.

Is this result easy to prove?

Thanks for any help!

Update: I think I have an inductive proof as such. First let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. We will get a corresponding $N(1/2)$, such that $\|f_m-f_n\|_p<1/2$ for $n,m\geq N(1/2)$.

Continuing inductively, we have $\|f_m-f_n\|_p<1/2^k$ for $n,m\geq N(1/2^k)$.

Then, we may take $g_1=f_{N(1/2)}, g_2=f_{N(1/4)},\dots, g_k=f_{N(1/2^k)}$.

[image]

Comment: It follows from $f_n$ being a Cauchy sequence: terms get arbitrarily close.

Comment: Thanks! Is this result easy to prove?

Comment: Try with a Cauchy sequence of real numbers to see the intuition. That worked for me.